# IF statement relating to timestamps

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I am retrieving comments using a foreach and I am trying to code in an if statement that declares that if the time stamps created_at and updated_at are equal then I will only show the created at time stamp but if they are different i want to show both. how would i do this? so far i have this which throws an error telling me their is an error with the if statment...

Models:

```
 public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','batsmen_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
```

Controllers:

```
public function getSingle($slug)
{
    //fetch from the database based on slug.
    $batsmen = Batsmen::with('comments')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();


    //return view
    return view('batsmen.single')->withBatsmen($batsmen);

}
```

View:

```
@foreach($batsmen->comments as $comments)
@if($comments->created_at = $comments->updated_at)
Posted at {{$comments->created_at}}
@else
Posted at {{$comments->created_at}}
Updated at {{$comments->updated_at}}

@endIf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@if($comments->created_at = $comments->updated_at)`

This is incorrect, a single equals sign is an assignment operator. To compare to vales you need to use either `==` or `===`.

`==` compares two values whereas `===` compares both value and type.

Laravel uses the `Carbon` library throughout the framework for working with dates. It has some useful helper functions for comparing dates in many different formats saving you some legwork.

```
Carbon::parse($date1)->eq(Carbon::parse($date2))
```

Would tell you if two dates are equal.

When you have carbon objects already you can do

```
$comments->created_at->eq( $comments->updated_at);
```

Comment: nice one man, any ideas to this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388014/if-statement-on-if-all-records-being-shown-or-not